# Find the global and local extrema.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have the following function:

$f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(x,y)=x^2-xy+y^2-x+2y$

with $A=[0,1]^2$.

I need to find the local and global extrema.

---

Please help me checking if im right: I need to find the local extrema. To do so I'm using the fact that for such an local Max or Min $a$ I have $\nabla f(a)=0$.

If I find the local ones the biggest of them would be the Max and the smallest the Min global Extrema.

I need the check all critical points:

$f(0,y), f(1,y), f(x,0), f(x,0), f(x,1), f(0,0), f(1,1)$

My solution is: 
Global Minimum: $(1/2,0)$
Global Maximum: $(1,1)$

My questions:
1. Is this approach right?
2. Why I have to check these points (I don't understand the reason behind)
3. Is there an possibility to check via computer if these are the right solutions?

Thanks

Comment: i have got the Minimum as $$-\frac{1}{4}$$ and will be reached for $$x=\frac{1}{2},y=0$$

Comment: Ok, thats the same I've get for Minimum

Answer (score 0):

If you do as you said and put the divergence equal to $0$, then you would get a system of linear equations, with equations and two unknowns. The solution would be $(0,-1)$, which is out of the region. In such a case, you should search boundaries of the region to find global minimum and maximum.

Then, you may pay attention to each derivative separately. The derivative, with respect to $y$ is always positive, which means that if you start from a point $(x_0,y_0)$ and increase the second component, then the value of $f(x_0,y_0)$ should be increasing. So, you should search for your global extreme values on the boundaries $([0,1],0)$ and $([0,1],1)$.

Now, you need to turn to the derivative, with respect to $x$. Plug in $y=0$ in the derivative and put it equal to $0$. Solve it for $x$ to find the minimum. For, the maximum, the same process, while plugging in $y=1$ instead.